# Check for count of UpperCase

Tags: java, uppercase

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Test{
  public static int countUppercase(String s){
  int count = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
 if(s.charAt(i)>='A'&&s.charAt(i)<='Z'){
 count++;
}
} 

 return count;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("Please enter a word to check for uppercase:");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  String s=input.nextLine();
  countUppercase(s);
   }
 }
```

Why doesn't this code work ?
It just takes the input but does not return the count !

Comment: I'm assuming your goal is to print the result? If that's the case, you'll want to use `System.out.println`

Comment: Then what does the return do if I print it??

Comment: `return` makes the result of a method available to the caller (in this case `main`). It's up to the caller what to do with the returned value. If you want to print it, main needs to say "Print the value returned by this method." Or in code: `System.out.println(countUppercase(s));`

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(countUppercase(s));
```

Because you are not printing the output

Comment: Shouldn't the return print the value of count ?

Comment: No it just returns the value to the call of the function
 int c = countUppercase(s);
Now c will have the count. The value is returned to c. And its better to use isUpper()

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
{
     count++;
}
```

**EDIT**
I just executed your code. Its works fine. Only thing is that you are **not priniting** the result. Is that your problem?

```
int nUpperCase = countUppercase(s);
System.out.println(nUpperCase );
```

Comment: welcome :) using `Character.isUpperCase` is a better approach according to me. (Why write some functionality if java already provides it)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it does not return the count?

When you call the method:

```
countUppercase(s);
```

you don't use the return value.

Try this for example:

```
int count = countUppercase(s);
System.out.println("count is " + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing the output.
You can also try below code:

```
for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
{
     for(char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++)
    {
           if (input.charAt(i) == c)
          {
                    upperCaseCount++;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: @user1804697: If any of the above answer that works for you, then please accept that answer. So that it can help others.